# Installing in encrypted partition under EFI boot

Tags: dual-boot, encryption, grub-efi, debootstrap

I've been googleing for a bit and can not find an answer yet

Im from a FreeBSD background, so you will have to forgive me a little

I am trying to dual boot FreeBSD and Ubuntu

I want to set up a completely encrypted installation, including /boot
I have looked at the GRUB2 modules and there is crypt and lvm, so GRUB should (hopefully) be able to unlock the encrypted partition

I have set up my disk as follows (In a VBox session, until I get everything working, then it will be on the real drive)

sda 100Gb
sda1 100Mb (EFI)
sda2 8Gb (FreeBSD Swap)
sda3 8Gb (FreeBSD zfs boot)
sda4 40G (FreeBSD zfs root)
sda5 43.9G (Ubuntu LVM crypt)

lvm
vg-swap 8Gb
vg-root 35.9Gb

From what I've read, if doing something unusual, many people suggest using the Alternative Installer image, but I cant find one for Ubuntu 16.

I've tried Ubuntu 16.04 desktop image, but the GUI installer will not let me install with an encrypted boot and is insisting that /boot must be on a none encrypted partition.

Does this mean that the only way I can have an encrypted boot in to install via the CLI? I did find debootstrap, but haven't figured out how to get GRUB to play nice with an encrypted boot. I am trying to get GRUB (on the EFI partition) to unlock the crypt container and boot the linux kernel
I have not managed to test debootstrap yet (because of my GRUB issues).

Is debootstrap the best way to achieve what I want?
Does anyone have any pointers to getting GRUB to play nice?

Thanks in advance
Paul

EDIT:1
So I'm a bit further forwards

I get GRUB to unlock the cryto parition and call initramfs

initramfs fails to complete with
Volume Group "vg" not found
Cannot process volume group vg

I can do
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda5 lvm
lvm
lvmdiskscan
exit
vgchange -ay
exit

That will allow the OS to continue on loading

So now to figure out how to have initramfs call cryptsetup on it's on

Comment: Never used encryption, but ran across this: http://www.pavelkogan.com/2014/05/23/luks-full-disk-encryption/

Comment: Maybe https://www.circuidipity.com/full-disk-encryption-ubuntu/ is helpful to someone